# Programmatically feed parameters to sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Say I have a `bash` script, that first parses parameters/files. As a result, the script generates the following string:

```
args="-e 's/\\\$foo\\b/bar/gi' -e 's/\\\$baz\\b/qux/gi'"
```

Now I want to feed the resulting string (`-e 's/\$foo\b/bar/gi' -e 's/\$baz\b/qux/gi'`) to sed in order to perform search and replace on for instance the following file:

```
Hello $foo, hello $baz
```

If one uses `sed -e 's/\$foo\b/bar/gi' -e 's/\$baz\b/qux/gi'`, it returns:

```
Hello bar, hello qux
```

If however one calls:

```
sed $args
```

it gives an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

How can I programmatically feed a sequence of parameters to `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid all the crazy escaping and declare `args` variable as a shell array:

```
args=(-e 's/\$foo\b/bar/gi' -e 's/\$baz\b/qux/gi')
```

and then use it in `sed` as:

```
s='Hello $foo, hello $baz'
echo "$s" | sed "${args[@]}"
Hello bar, hello qux
```

Comment: Since you are using single quotes in the array you can get away without the escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it into one string, to make it easier on the quoting:

```
sedargs="s/\$foo\b/bar/gi;s/\$baz\b/qux/gi"

sed "${sedargs}" <<< "Hello \$foo, hello \$baz"
```